# Por que, quando comparo 1000 e 500, 500 sempre é maior nessa função em JS?

Tags: javascript

Escrevi essa função em JavaScript que compara dois números e me diz qual deles é o maior:

```
    function verificarMaiorNumero(x,y){
      if (primeiroNumero > segundoNumero){
        return primeiroNumero + " é maior";
      }else{
        return segundoNumero + " é maior";
      }
    }
      var primeiroNumero = prompt("Digite um número: ");
        do{
          var segundoNumero = prompt("Digite outro número :");
        }while (primeiroNumero == segundoNumero);
        alert(verificarMaiorNumero(primeiroNumero,segundoNumero));
```

Porém, ao entrar com os valores `1000` e `500`, ela sempre me retorna dizendo que `500 é maior`. Por que isso acontece? Onde está o erro no código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função `prompt` retorna um valor em texto (uma *String*). Quando você deseja comparar números, você tem que utilizar valores do tipo inteiro.

Para isso basta utilizar `parseInt` ou `new Number`, por exemplo:

```js
function verificarMaiorNumero(x, y) {
  if (x > y) {
    return x + " é maior";
  } else {
    return y + " é maior";
  }
}
var primeiroNumero = parseInt(prompt("Digite um numero: "));

do {
  var segundoNumero = new Number(prompt("Digite outro numero:"));
} while (primeiroNumero == segundoNumero)

alert(verificarMaiorNumero(primeiroNumero, segundoNumero));
```